# Página modo paisagem não se ajusta

Tags: html, css, css3, layout-responsivo

Eu coloquei uma foto do fundo, tendo 100% de altura.

Quando abro o site pelo celular (ou console Chrome / Firefox) no modo paisagem, o fundo da imagem não ocupa todo o espaço.

No modo de área de trabalho e modo móvel na posição de retrato eles são ok. Só PAISAGEM de modo que é um problema.

Eu quero no modo paisagem, o conteúdo é definir a janela de exibição. Como fazer isso?

[image] MOBILE: MODE RETRATO, OK.

[image] MOBILE: MODE LANDSCAPE, a div não se ajusta de acordo com o conteúdo.

> OBS1: Rodem o Snippet no console do navegador. No simulador de dispositivos móveis para vocês entenderem o que quero dizer-fazer.

```css
body, html {
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;

}
.block {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;

}

.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;      
}

.centered {
  margin-top: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 500px; 
  background: white;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
     
    <div class="centered">
    
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/HP_logo_630x630.png" class="img-responsive" id="img_logo">
 <p style="color: black"> <a style="font-size:35px;"> xxxxxx</a> <br><br>text text <br> address <br>  </p>      
   </div>
  </div>
```

I tentei remover o **.block:before** e:

```
@media(orientation: landscape){
  .background-image {
    min-height: 200%;
  }
}
```

Mas, este efeito não funciona apenas no modo MOBILE. Ele funciona tanto no MOBILE quanto no DESKTOP. EU quero que funcione apenas no MOBILE.

Comment: No Desktop também não funciona direito :/

Comment: @Zkk você fez o teste no aparelho mesmo ou apenas em simuladores, as vezes os resultados divergem bastante...Publique seu site e acesse no seu celular mesmo.

Comment: Tanto aqui no stack quanto na minha máquina no desktop está funcionando. É somente a imagem no centro e nada mais! Também coloquei no ar e a mesma coisa. Destkop OK. Mobile (somente no modo PAISAGEM) Este erro.

Comment: Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Como eu disse o problema ocorre no desktop também e é devido ao `height: 100%`. Veja a resposta que formulei e o exemplo que postei pra tentar corrigir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se era isso que queria:

O que fiz foi remover o `.block:before`, como você disse, e adicionei a `.img-responsive` um `margin: auto` para centralizar.

Já a `div.block` e ao `body` ao invés de um `height: 100%` apliquei um `height: auto` e um `min-height: 100%`. Um simples `height: 100%` fará com que o `body` e `.block` se ajustem ao tamanho da tela e não aos elementos  quando estes ultrapassarem a tela. Essa configuração é importante para caso queira adicionar novos elementos a sua página, pois assim estes não passaram pelo mesmo problema de antes. Com um `height: auto` a `div.block` se ajustará ao tamanho de seu conteúdo, porém com um `min-height: 100%`, esta não se reduzirá a uma tamanho menor que a viewport.

Para finalizar, recomendo-lhe que tire o `margin-top: 10%` da `div.centered`, esse top em porcentagem pode resultar algumas situações desagradáveis, o melhor seria um valor fixo, como `50px`, por exemplo. Mas isso fica a seu critério. E caso queira uma distância do conteúdo na parte inferior, basta adicionar um `padding-bottom: 50px /*por exemplo*/`.

Estas reformulações colaborarão para um código mais funcional e melhor adaptável a novos elementos.

```css
body, html {
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.block {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
}
.centered {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 500px; 
  background: white;
}
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="centered">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/HP_logo_630x630.png" class="img-responsive" id="img_logo">
    <p style="color: black"> <a style="font-size:35px;"> xxxxxx</a>
      <br>
      <br>text text
      <br> address
      <br> </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [Exemplo - JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/845qezyr/4/embedded/result/#Result)

Comment: Era exatamente isso o que eu precisava. Com esta solução e mais alguns ajustes consegui o que queria, obrigado pela ajuda e pela dica com o espaçamento da **div.centered**.

Answer (score 2):

Então como disse o problema ocorre no Desktop também, isto é devido ao `height: 100%`, pois ele não trabalha com a altura máxima da página mas sim do `view-port`, uma maneira simples de resolver seria usar o `display: table` no `.block`, veja um exemplo:

```css
body, html {
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;

}
.block {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  display: table;

}

.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;      
}

.centered {
  margin-top: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 500px; 
  background: white;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
     
    <div class="centered">
    
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/HP_logo_630x630.png" class="img-responsive" id="img_logo">
 <p style="color: black"> <a style="font-size:35px;"> xxxxxx</a> <br><br>text text <br> address <br>  </p>      
   </div>
  </div>
```

Veja o resultado na imagem:

[image: Imagem na tela landspace]

Comment: Ótima opção, bem sucinta e funcional..

Comment: @SamirBraga Obrigado! me permite tirar uma duvida? Por que não usa o Stack Snippet ao invés do jsfiddle? Eu ia mover o seu exemplo pra ele, mas fiquei curioso. De qualquer maneira +1 na sua sua resposta

Comment: O link  do JsFiddle leva para o result, assim ele poderá lá mesmo redimensionar no console e verificar, mas não há mal algum em usar o Stack Snippet... vou até editar a resposta. E obrigado.

Comment: @SamirBraga entendi, toda via aqui ele também pode redimensionar e ainda tem o uso das ferramentas no Firefox e Chrome, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4206/3635

Comment: Você tem razão...rsrs, enfim foi o costume. E ter os duas opções é sempre bom :).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou!! Sobre a discussão, vejo o Snippet do Stack como uma ótima forma de visualização, mas se um terceiro precisar editar algo, o JSFiddle é mais simples para isso.